# Installing PHP bitwasp bitcoin library

Tags: php, bitwasp

I am attempting to set up the PHP bitwasp library from the github repository:

https://github.com/Bit-Wasp/bitcoin-php

The installing instructions suggest I simply execute:

`$ composer require bitwasp/bitcoin`

I do have `composer` installed but I am getting the following error message:

`Problem 1
    - Installation request for bitwasp/bitcoin dev-master -> satisfiable by bitwasp/bitcoin[dev-master].
    - Can only install one of: bitwasp/bitcoin[v0.0.29.1, dev-master].
    - Installation request for bitwasp/bitcoin v0.0.29.1 -> satisfiable by bitwasp/bitcoin[v0.0.29.1].`

I do not practice PHP full time so I lack the experience of installing packages in that language and using `composer`. I would be grateful if someone could point me in the right direction.

**EDIT**
The suggestion has been made that the package is already installed. However, the following code sample which I got from another thread:

```
<?php
// failing to install bitwasp
use BitWasp\Bitcoin\Bitcoin;
use BitWasp\Bitcoin\Address;
use BitWasp\Bitcoin\Key\PrivateKeyFactory;

$network = Bitcoin::getNetwork();

$privateKey = PrivateKeyFactory::create(true);
$publicKey = $privateKey->getPublicKey();
$address = $publicKey->getAddress();

?>
```

is giving me `PHP Fatal error:  Class 'BitWasp\Bitcoin\Bitcoin' not found`.

Comment: Did you include the vendor/autoload.php file? It's missing from your snippet, so as suggested below, it might already be on your system.

Comment: You have made me very happy !!! First of all I had to type `composer install` instead of `composer require bitswap/bitcoin` and this triggered a proper installation, and in particular this created a `vendor` directory with an `autoload.php` file in it. Then I created a symbolic link from my working directory to this `vendor` directory. Then I added the line `require 'vendor/autoload.php';` in my snippet as you suggested. And voila the thing ran :) Thank you very much !!. If you want to explain the answer for the record (better than I can do, I am no PHP specialist) I will gladly upvote it.  .

Comment: Oh, please be careful :P someone published bitswap/bitcoin on composer and I'm not sure if they're typo-squatting! If you can, @Sven could you update your comment if this wasn't what you meant?

Comment: `require 'vendor/autoload.php'; `For those having similar issues.

Answer (score 1):

You have it installed already. That's why it's saying you have the requirements met and don't need to download it again.

Comment: Thank you very much ! I am guessing something else is wrong too. I have updated my question to explain.

Comment: I think I know why. Did you use "bitcoin" instead of "bitcoin-php"?

Comment: I typed `composer require bitwasp/bitcoin` to install and the code is exactly as I have stated it. Using the indicated repository. I am on Debian 8.

Comment: Oh, im not familiar with Debian. What php version are you using?

Comment: `PHP 5.6.24. Zend Engine v2.6.0 with Zend OPcache v7.0.6-dev`. This is pure PHP, run as a script (no browser involed), if this matters.